# Where do Hike and WhatsApp store their messages?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

Does anyone here knows where Hike/WhatsApp store their messages? I know WhatsApp's Database can be found on the SD card, but it is created every day at 4 AM, and deleted if the file is more than 7 days old I want to know where they store their messages because they also read and displays messages at runtime.

So I want to know, where do these two programs store messages? I need to format my SD card so I want to make a backup for my messages.

Comment: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23756533

Comment: ok im just checking the link, but do you know any thing about hike?? ok just tell me how do i get my all messages back after resetting/flashing my phone??

Answer (score 1):

**For WhatsApp:**

Backups can be found at:
`/sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/`
(Use this tool to decrypt it: [WhatsApp Key/DB Extractor](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982) or [WhatCrypt](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2689911))

Live database can be found at (requires root):
`/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db`

---

**For Hike:**

Backup can be found at:
`/sdcard/Hike/Backup/chats.backup`

Live database can be found at (requires root):
`/data/data/com.bsb.hike/databases/chats`

Answer (score 0):

if you use same email and mobile number you can get the data. as per my knowledge the messages data will be stored in the email and mobile connectivity of the whats app and hike messenger database of these services.

Comment: Realy? because im gonna flashing my phone, so im little afraid of it, and i dont think hike saves those messages in their server for long time, there must be a file from which hike loads all messages at runtime, im sure here must be someone who knows this, because how can be this possible that the whole world could'nt know a little thing...

Comment: yes u can save your chat data to your emila id, as i too got such information hike support members over twitter. here you the repliy from that hike supprot member tweeted, "No, you would loose your chats by doing so :( The only way to save your chats is by emailing them to your personal accnt."

Comment: That means its impossible, but how can apps like hike store datas there? that means they have the root access or access to /data drive? and if yes that means an app can give me the power to access it, will it?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.hike.in/entries/85325208-I-am-switching-to-a-new-android-phone-How-do-I-save-my-chat-backup-and-restore-in-new-phone-

Here. Just copy the hike folder of the SD card. Most likely, there is some encrypted file present here that stores messages as well as images in this very folde . Goodluck.